# In my broadcast receiver 's onreceive() method, how can I tell the origin of the Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In the broadcast receiver's onReceive() method, how can I tell which app send me the Intent?

Comment: Is it not  the idea that  you would not know unless it is put  into the intent?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571564/android-pendingintent-extras-not-received-by-broadcastreceiver/14612215#14612215

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the intent of how android uses Intents (no pun intended.).  However, if you are sending the intent and your broadcaster is receiving the intent, you can use setExtra ( String, String) on the Intent to attach the name of the class sending the intent.  Inside your onReceive, check to see if that extra is set and, if it is, check to see if the value matches your expected class.